# why is my error not showing in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

Im trying to plot an error graph but when I run it, it does not show anything.

```
x = linspace(-10,10,100);
h = logspace(-1,-16,100);
error = (300);
figure(1);
hold on;
for i = 1:100
    error(i) = abs(1-(exp(h(i)-exp(h(i))))/(h(i)));
    plot(x,error(i));
end
disp([error']);
```

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html): `If one of X or Y is a scalar and the other is either a scalar or a vector, then the plot function plots discrete points. However, to see the points you must specify a marker symbol, for example, plot(X,Y,'o').`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing the computations and the plotting operations within a `for` loop, you can vectorize the whole process to achieve a correct result together with a better performance. Just remember to convert your scalar operators to element-wise operators in order to avoid size consistency errors (for instance, `./` must be used instead of `/`).

Here is the code:

```
x = linspace(-10,10,100);
h = logspace(-1,-16,100);
error = abs(1 - (exp(h - exp(h)) ./ h));
plot(x,error);
```

And here is the result:

[image: Result]